# How many Pokemon in X & Y are Legendaries?

Tags: pokemon-x-y, pokemon-sixth-generation

So I'm pretty sure there's at least 2, one for both X & Y.   Much like other iterations of the other Pokemon games, are there other Legendaries? How many legendaries, and what are their names?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are 3 Kalos (Generation VI) legendary Pokémon, and 4 Kanto (Generation I) legendary Pokémon available in Pokemon X & Y.

#### Kalos Legendaries

- [#716 **Xerneas**](http://www.serebii.net/pokedex-xy/716.shtml) / [#717 **Yveltal**](http://www.serebii.net/pokedex-xy/717.shtml)

  - Found as part of the story (Team Flare's HQ) at level 50.
  - Version Specific (X has Xerneas, Y has Yvetal)
  - Both are stationary
- [#718 **Zygarde**](http://www.serebii.net/pokedex-xy/718.shtml)

  - Available after the Elite 4, in both X & Y
  - Found on the bottom floor of Terminus Cave at level 70
  - stationary
- [#719 **Diancie**](http://www.serebii.net/pokedex-xy/719.shtml)

  - Available only through a [special event](http://www.serebii.net/events/dex/719.shtml)
- [#720 **Hoopa**](http://www.serebii.net/pokedex-xy/720.shtml)

  - Available only through a [special event](http://www.serebii.net/events/dex/720.shtml)

#### Kanto Legendaries

- [#144 **Articuno**](http://www.serebii.net/pokedex-xy/144.shtml) / [#145 **Zapdos**](http://www.serebii.net/pokedex-xy/145.shtml) / [#146 **Moltres**](http://www.serebii.net/pokedex-xy/146.shtml)

  - Randomly encountered wandering after defeating the Elite 4.
  - You can only encounter one, which is dependent on which starter Pokemon you chose:

    1. Chespin -> Articuno
    2. Fennekin -> Zapdos
    3. Froakie -> Moltres
  - They will flee automatically 12 times when you encounter them, after which they will go to the Sea Spirit's Den where you can finally battle them. [Source](http://www.serebii.net/xy/legendary.shtml).
- [#150 **Mewtwo**](http://www.serebii.net/pokedex-xy/150.shtml)

  - Available after the Elite 4, in the cave in Pokemon Village:

    > After defeating the Elite Four, a man will stop blocking a cave within the Pokémon Village. In this cave, you will find nothing but a solitary Mewtwo with its back against the door. Interact with it and a cutscene will occur where it notices you and attacks. After defeating it, you will receive the Mewtwonite X or Y item depending on your version. - [Source](http://www.serebii.net/xy/legendary.shtml)

Comment: What about mewtwo? Because how else will you be able to get Mega Mewtwo X/Y?

Comment: @Haidro Mewtwo is a Gen 1 legendary. The question was about Gen 6 ones.

Comment: @Nolonar Ah, you are correct

Comment: FWIW, the Gen 1 birds are also in the game.

Comment: So not a total of 3 then

Comment: @Retrosaur Right, right, good catch.

Comment: Should this be updtaed with newer event Pokemon, or only those catchable in game? If events, there is a Diancie event soon (I know at least in US/UK), and you can get Celebi through the PokeBank app.

Comment: @Geobits I've not kept up on these kinds of things lately, but in my opinion they should, as long as they are actually available. I'll look into these things and provide an update probably later tonight.

Answer (score 2):

Nintendo should also be releasing a Rock/Fairy type pokemon called Diancie which is also supposed to be a legendary

Comment: Anything to support that claim?

Comment: http://www.idigitaltimes.com/articles/20576/20131029/pokemon-x-y-new-hoopa-diancie-volcanion.htm     http://bmgf.bulbagarden.net/f323/diancie-volcanion-hoopa-leaked-rumor-157662/  http://www.serebii.net/index2.shtml

Comment: They should also be releasing Volcanion and Hoopa

Comment: Heh no problem!

Comment: Nintendo don't make the Pokemon games, Game Freak does.

Answer (score 1):

You can find Articuno Zapdos or Moltres (depending on which starter you chose) in the wild, but it flees as soon as you see it (to obtain one you must locate one ten times then it will rest in the sea spirit's den, and you will be able to fight it like Zygarde or Mewtwo). They are first generation Legendary pokémon.

You can find Mewtwo with Mewtwonite at the Pokemon Village, in a cave where you need Surf and Waterfall to reach.

You can find Zygarde in the Terminus Cave; you don't need the Rock Smash TM.

Comment: Actually you have to encounter the Legendary bird 12 times.