# How many Legendary Pokemon are in X and Y?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

In Pokemon Black 2 and White 2, there were a lot of legendaries, not just from Unova but from other regions as well.  I know that Yveltal (I am playing Y version), Mewtwo and the legendary birds are in the game.  Are there other legendary Pokemon in the game other than those 5?

Comment: @Union No, I'm talking about the number of legendary Pokemon in the whole game, including other gen legendaries, not just sixth gen.

Comment: Definitely not a duplicate of the linked question, but the answer for it does seem to answer this question, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, there are seven regular legendaries in the game(s).

The three "letter" (I just made this term up myself) legendaries are:

- Xerneas - Only obtainable in Pokemon X
- Yveltal - Only obtainable in Pokemon Y
- Zygarde

You can also catch Mewtwo, which can be evolved into Mega Mewtwo X/Y.

And finally, you can get **one of** the *roaming*, legendary bird trio:

- Articuno (if your starter is Chespin)
- Zapdos (if your starter is Fennekin)
- Moltres (if your starter is Froakie)

A method for catching the roaming legendaries can be found [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/135358/where-do-you-get-the-first-generation-legendaries-in-x-and-y/135837#135837). It's not the same as earlier generations.

Answer (score -2):

Currently, it doesn't seem like other legendaries will be available.
This does open up the prospect of legendary DLC, though, which could be interesting.

Comment: Though, I have been hearing rumors of the "Z" Pokemon. Who is this Pokemon?

Comment: they could add all the legendaries if they release a Pokemon Z later on

Comment: Answer is wrong, that "Z" pokemon is Zygarde and it's in the game.

Comment: @Shinrai `it's in the game` as in "you can encounter and catch it", or as in "we won't need any DLC to get it, but we'll need to wait for an event"?

Comment: @Nolonar - The former.  Think of this guy as the current Rayquaza/Giratina/Kyurem.

Answer (score -2):

You can catch 'Zygarde' in terminus cave. He is at the back of the cave. Also if you search around in the area where 'Zygarde' resides you can find the adamant, lustrous, and griseous orbs.